# twilio: detecting that a dial target is busy?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, twilio, status, detect

I'm using the twilio REST interface via flask under python3.

I am using the `dial` method to route incoming calls to another number (stored in the `target` variable), as follows:

```
resp = VoiceResponse()
resp.dial(
    target,
    action=url_for('callstatus'),
    method='GET',
    timeout=20
)
return Response(str(resp), 200, mimetype='application/xml')
```

This works with no problem if the target number starts ringing. However, if the target number is busy, the `dial` method does not detect this, and it just lets the caller hear the busy signal until the timeout occurs.

I'd like to somehow immediately detect that the target is busy and then route the call to voicemail in that case.

I know how to do the routing to voicemail, but I don't know how to make this happen automatically upon encountering a busy signal.

Is there any way to do this via the twilio REST API?

UPDATE: I tried the following, and it didn't work ...

```
resp = VoiceResponse()
dial = Dial(
    action=url_for('callstatus'),
    method='GET',
    timeout=20
)
dial.number(
    target,
    status_callback=url_for('callstatus'),
    status_callback_event='initiated ringing answered completed',
    status_callback_method='GET'
)
resp.append(dial)
return Response(str(resp), 200, mimetype='application/xml')
```

When I do it this way, I get a busy signal, and it goes on forever. The time out in the original `Dial` object gets ignored.

NOTE: I based the above code on this following example within the twilio documentation for `Number` ...

```
response = VoiceResponse()
dial = Dial()
dial.number(
    '+14158675310',
    status_callback_event='initiated ringing answered completed',
    status_callback='https://myapp.com/calls/events',
    status_callback_method='POST'
)
response.append(dial)

print(response)
```

ANOTHER NOTE: the `status_callback` is ignored within the `number` object. If I comment out `action` in the `dial` object, my status callback never gets called, even if I hang up the call. And if I put `action` back into the `dial` object and comment out all the `status_callback` attributes in the `number` object, the action callback ***does*** get called when I hang up the call. This means that `action` is being recognized, but `status_callback` is being ignored.

... and I get exactly the same behavior, whether I set the method to `POST` or `GET`.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You could try using `<Number>` within the `<Dial>` you have there and including a [`statusCallback` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-status-callback). When the dialled number is busy, Twilio will send a webhook to say that the call is completed and the reason was that it was busy. You could then [use the REST API to modify the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress) and send it to some new TwiML to collect voicemail.

Alternatively, you could put the incoming call into a queue with `<Enqueue>` and use the REST API to dial out to the phone number. If that call then comes back as busy you can redirect the incoming call out of the queue and into voicemail. If the outbound call is a success then you respond with `<Dial>` and `<Queue>` to connect the callers.

Comment: Thank you, but the `<Number>` object does not specify a time out. In my example above, I want the connection to time out after 20 seconds, at which time I route the call to voice mail (via the `action` URL). How would I specify a time out with `<Number>`?

Comment: You still specify the timeout on the `<Dial>` then nest the `<Number>` within.

Comment: I did that, and it didn't work. I am posting my code above within my original question. Should be there in a couple minutes

Comment: I apologise, my phone doesn't seem to do busy signals (I get call waiting or straight to voicemail), so I'm unable to test with this. Perhaps you could try the `<Enqueue>` based flow?

Comment: I'll give the `<Enqueue>` method a try. Will get to it tomorrow, and I'll report back.

Comment:  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: It looks like I will need another day or two before I can test `<Enqueue>`. However, I don't see how it can do what I want. In the case where the line is ***not*** busy, I don't want to play music or some canned verbal response to the caller.  I want the caller to hear the phone ringing, and unless I missed something, I don't see an option for that in `<Enqueue>`. But I will dig deeper and try some things when I have more time.

Comment: I indeed was not able to get `<Enqueue>` to work the way I want. I do not want music or a canned voice response to be played while the caller is waiting for the forwarded number to  be answrered. I want the caller to hear the normal phone-ringing sound when the forwarded number is ringing. Also, busy detection didn't work with `<Enqueue>`, either.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how else to help right now, as I said before my phone doesn't return a busy signal so I can't test. Perhaps you could get in contact with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and see what they suggest.

Comment: How do you manage to have the busy event showing up? Is there anything special to do? We only ever get the `completed` status independently of wether the target number was busy, canceled the call or answered normally.

Comment: You should get the completed event, but the parameter `CallStatus` sent to the webhook will hold the reason, such as `busy` or `no-answer`.